# button that refresh data

Tags: python, django, forms

but he is returning directly the chackou and I want that only if it is chosen returns him

I'll simplify it so I can understand it, I need it in model.py, when the person chooses the "SIM" option that adds and updates the chekout with datatimenow, but I can not do it

Model.py

```
SAIDA_CHOICES = (
    ('Não', 'Não Pago'),
    ('Sim', 'Pago')
)

class MovRotativo(models.Model):
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=False, null=False,)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    valor_hora = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)
    chk = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SAIDA_CHOICES)

     def saida(self):
        if self.chk == 'sim':
            return self.chk
        else:
            self.checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
            return self.checkout
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to implement the entire window as a subclass of a tk Frame, and then destroy and recreate it. Your code might look something like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        <other code here...>

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.frame = None
        refreshButton = tk.Button(self.root, text="refresh", command=self.refresh)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        if self.frame is not None:
            self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Example(self.root)
        self.frame.grid(...)
```

Though,there's nothing really magical about subclassing Frame. You just need to have a function that creates a frame and puts a bunch of widgets in it. When you want to refresh, just delete the frame and call your function again. Using a class is a bit more convenient, but a class isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: very good, I'm going to use this, but my doubt is how to update the database with this button data

Comment: I'll simplify it so I can understand it, I need it in the model, when the person chooses the option "YES" it triggers and updates the chekout with the datatimenow

Comment: If you find my answer helpful please vote me up. thanks